# Phpmysql report data changed after updating one mysql table

Tags: sql, mysql

I am generating report from following MySQL query which consist of two tables. 1)Consultant and 2) iap4. `Consultant` table consist of  `consultant_name` and `share1`, where as `iap4` table consists of  `docname`, `qty`, `price1`, `discount`, `tot4` and `tech1`.

```
SELECT 
    share1, docname, qty, price1, discount, tot4, tech 
FROM 
    consultant 
INNER JOIN 
    iap4 ON consultant.consultant_name = iap4.docname
```

This is sample data for both tables:

[image]

All is working fine in reporting. But when I update consultant share in table consultant, then it also update all the previous data with new updating share. I want to learn is there any way by which we can stop affect of updated share1 on previous entered records.

Here is the query structure:

[image]

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors). [Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055/tips-for-asking-a-good-structured-query-language-sql-question). Data should be provided as text. And this seems to be a database design question and have very little to do with PHP, as far as I can see.

Comment: yes agree it is database design question sir! PHP tag is mentioned by mistake

Comment: Anyway if you want to report the "share" value for each row in iap4 as it existed when that row was created, then either you need to store a separate value for "share" in the iap4 table to preserve it against each row in there - or you need to create a share_history table related to the consultant, which shows the share value and the date it was created, and also the iap4 table would need to have a date field, and then when you're joining them you'd need to work out the date overlap and see which share history record relates to which iap4 record.

Comment: If I've misunderstood your requirements though please say so - you didn't provide a complete example of your expected results, so it's always going to be slightly a matter of speculation

Comment: @ADyson sir! yours answer is absolutely correct. i thnk separate share history table will be fine . and i can add time stamp in both table . and when for example i have to update consultant share for doctor AAA, instead of changing that value, i will add new row where all values will be the same expect time stamp.